# jQuery .removeClass() issue only in Chrome, working fine in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird issue. I am using `removeClass` and `addClass` in `jquery` but they are working fine in **IE** and not working as expected in **Chrome**. The class is getting added and removed but the effect is not visible in Chrome. That is while the pop-ups come, on click of Yes the next text-box should get red border and another pop-up should appear but the border change is not happening in Chrome.

1. On load certain text-box have red border.
2. On click of Start button, all text box have no border and pop-up appears and certain text box gets red border.
3. On click of Yes, another popup appears and another text box gets red border.
4. On click of Cancel, pop-up stops and the only current text box has red border.

Please check the inserted snippet in both chrome and IE and tell why this irregular behavior. Below is the working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var grid = jQuery('[id$="gvTest"]')[0];
  var rows = grid.rows;
  for (var k = 1; k < rows.length; k++) {
    var textBoxInitial = jQuery(rows[k]).find('input.newName');
    if (textBoxInitial.val() == "Article1") {
      textBoxInitial.addClass("redColorBorder");
    }
  }
});
function proceedCopyValidation() {
  var grid = jQuery('[id$="gvTest"]')[0];
  var rows = grid.rows;
  for (var k = 1; k < rows.length; k++) {
    var textBoxInitial = jQuery(rows[k]).find('input.newName');
    if (textBoxInitial.hasClass("redColorBorder")) {
      textBoxInitial.removeClass("redColorBorder");
    }
  }
  for (var k = 1; k < rows.length; k++) {
    var textBox = jQuery(rows[k]).find('input.newName');
    var newName = textBox.val();
    var isValid = newName == "Article1" ? true : false;
    if (isValid == true) {
      textBox.addClass("redColorBorder");
      var confirm = disp_confirm(k);
      if (!confirm) {
        return false;
      } else {
        if (textBox.hasClass("redColorBorder")) {
          textBox.removeClass("redColorBorder");
        }
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
function disp_confirm(count) {
  var r = confirm("A  pop-up here");
  return r;
}
```

```css
.redColorBorder {
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" id="ctl01">
        <span id="FeaturedContent_Label1">Done here</span>
        <div>
          <table class="GridNew " cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest" style="border-color:#CED1D5;width:650px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="headerColor">
                <th class="headerColor" scope="col">Old Name</th>
                <th class="headerColor" scope="col" style="width:15%;">New Name</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 1</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl02$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_0" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 2</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl03$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article2" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_1" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 3</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl04$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_2" class="newName redColorBorder" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 4</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl05$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_3" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="return proceedCopyValidation();" id="FeaturedContent_btnStart">
      </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it doesn't work in chrome because when a alert is thrown it blocks the ui thread so the rest of your code is not executed (add/remove red border).

I fixed your code to work in both ie and Chrome (didn't test for mozilla)

see the setTimeout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var grid = jQuery('[id$="gvTest"]')[0];
  var rows = grid.rows;
  for (var k = 1; k < rows.length; k++) {
    var textBoxInitial = jQuery(rows[k]).find('input.newName');
    if (textBoxInitial.val() == "Article1") {
      textBoxInitial.addClass("redColorBorder");
    }
  }
});
function proceedCopyValidation() {
  var grid = jQuery('[id$="gvTest"]')[0];
  var rows = grid.rows;
  
  $('input.newName.redColorBorder').removeClass("redColorBorder");
  
  var fnExec = function(idx) {
 if (idx == rows.length)
  return;
    var textBox = jQuery(rows[idx]).find('input.newName');
    var newName = textBox.val();
    var isValid = newName == "Article1" ? true : false;
    if (isValid == true) {
      textBox.addClass("redColorBorder");
   setTimeout(function(){
  var confirm = disp_confirm(idx);
  if (confirm) {
   if (textBox.hasClass("redColorBorder")) {
     textBox.removeClass("redColorBorder");
   }
   fnExec(idx+1);
  }
   }, 10);
    }
 else {
  fnExec(idx+1);
 }
  }
  fnExec(1);
  
}
function disp_confirm(count) {
  var r = confirm("A  pop-up here");
  return r;
}
```

```css
.redColorBorder {
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
    </head>  
    <body>
      <form method="post" id="ctl01">
        <span id="FeaturedContent_Label1">Done here</span>
        <div>
          <table class="GridNew " cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest" style="border-color:#CED1D5;width:650px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="headerColor">
                <th class="headerColor" scope="col">Old Name</th>
                <th class="headerColor" scope="col" style="width:15%;">New Name</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 1</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl02$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_0" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 2</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl03$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article2" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_1" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 3</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl04$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_2" class="newName redColorBorder" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="alignleft" style="width:15%;">Product 4</td>
                <td class="alignleft">
                  <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvTest$ctl05$TextBox1" type="text" value="Article1" id="FeaturedContent_gvTest_TextBox1_3" class="newName" style="width:80%;">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <input name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="return proceedCopyValidation();" id="FeaturedContent_btnStart">
      </form>
    </body>
```

Regards,

Thibaud P.

Comment: But here the request goes to server even if the validations fail or the user clicks on Cancel..